# Add a custom class to woocommerce recent product reviews div

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a class to `<div class="star-rating">` located in [content-widget-reviews.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-widget-reviews.php) ( in woocommerce template )
displayed here: 
`<?php echo wc_get_rating_html( intval( get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true ) ) ); ?>`

I want to make my template work with Bootstrap 4 ( see caps below )
[float right needs to be removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE2am.png) vs.
[wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6hFt.png)

I tried this solution below, but it adds the classes on the whole template ( I just want to add this class to the widget area)

```
// Widget review Stars
function myfuntion_wc_get_rating_html($html) {
// Replace link classes
$html = str_replace('<div class="star-rating"', '<div class="star-rating float-none text-primary"', $html);
return $html;
}
add_filter("woocommerce_product_get_rating_html", "myfuntion_wc_get_rating_html")
```

;

Is there a way to add my custom class directly on this code ?

```
<?php echo wc_get_rating_html( intval( get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true ) ) ); ?>
```

Thanks

P.S. I'd like to avoid the use of Jquery and CSS

Answer (score 0):

Did you try replacing WooCommerce template in your theme like described here https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ ?

> Edit files in an upgrade-safe way using overrides. Copy the template
>   into a directory within your theme named /woocommerce keeping the same
>   file structure but removing the /templates/ subdirectory.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I did, but I am unable to add the class I want to the code